# sp_reset_connection error in SQL Azure Linked Server RPC

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database, rpc, linked-server

I have a problem calling a remote Stored Procedure (RPC) on my SQL Azure, passing through a Linked Server (build on a Sql Server 2008 R2 instance: 10.50.2550.0  - x64 - Enterprise Edition).

This issue is not difficult to reproduce, and it's not really related with "calling" the Stored Procedure, but with its internal execution (I think)...

Take a look to my simple code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProcedure]
    @AccountId INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[myTable];

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[myTable] (Col1, Col2)
        SELECT DISTINCT
            Value1
            , Value2
        FROM [dbo].[myTableSource];
END
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[myStoredProcedure] TO [myDbRole]
GO
```

When I launch this through my Linked Server, using this code (on a connection from my local instance, where the Linked Server has been created)...

```
EXEC('[AZURE_LINKEDSERVER].[myDatabase].[dbo].[myStoredProcedure] @AccountId = NULL')
```

...I get this error (that seems a warning!):

```
Message 2812, level 16, state 62, row 1
Could not find stored procedure 'sp_reset_connection'.
```

And obviously I checked everywhere and I'm not calling that Stored Procedure...that I think it's internally used by Sql Server.

I also tried this code, same result:

```
EXEC sp_sqlexec '[AZURE_LINKEDSERVER].[myDatabase].[dbo].[myStoredProcedure] NULL'
```

The Linked Server has "remote RPC enabled" (`rpc` and `rpc out` options are both set to `True`) and works great with other Stored Procedure and every other OPENQUERY code I used until now: also permissions work fine.

The strange thing is that the first part of the SP is correctly executed (I see query result count in the Messages window of SSMS), but the second is not called at all.

Can you please tell what's the SP `sp_reset_connection` is related to?
Do you know a workaround to call my SP without errors?
I tried everything...

SQL Azure in use has version 11.0.9231

Answer (score 1):

sp_reset_connection is not an actual stored procedure it is a flag in the TDS stream that says "Reset the connection" so you can use connection pooling. It should exist on all SQL Servers implicitly but cannot be called by your code.

what type of linked server have you setup? follow this to create a linked server to azure:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/03/08/linked-servers-to-sql-azure.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the answer: the Linked Server has been created correctly...every ad-hoc query works fine, also single-line SPs work! Every Linked Server option is set correctly (I checked you link)...do you know a way to disable the sp_reset_connection "flag"? Why is it called by Sql Server connection in this way?!

Comment: no it is done at the protocol level - if you make the call through ssms does it work? It really does sound like someone has put in a call to sp_reset_connection as I have never seen it fail like this - please double check all your code as it is deployed to sql (actually choose to modify it rather than looking in source code) and ensure it isn't there anywhere

Comment: No, there are no calls at all: you can try with my code...also from SSMS, it doensn't wok!